# WARNING: The option setting is experimental and unsupported

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have updated **Android Studio** to **3.3.2**, and found gradle sync warning.

WARNING: The option setting **'android.databinding.enableV2=false'** is *experimental and unsupported*.
The current default is **'true'.**

WARNING: The option setting **'android.enableExperimentalFeatureDatabinding=true'** is *experimental and unsupported*.
The current default is **'false'.**

Answer (score 1):

In `gradle.properties` you can set
`android.useNewApkCreator=true`, This will fix first warning.